# Rerun node app on WebStorm after code change

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I recently started to use WebStorm and before this I used to use nodemon as a supervisor, so it watches any code change and restart the server.

How can I reach the same effect running node by the IDE?
Thanks!

**[EDIT]**

While there's no 9 version/live edit I'm posting my **solution**:

It's just have nodemon installed globaly and used it as a Node Parameter in the project configuration.

More details and screenshot below:

- Discover where is the nodemon's path;

  - Here (OSX) is "/usr/local/bin/nodemon" and it could be discovered using "which nodemon" (on terminal);
- Use this path in the Node Parameter field;

  - Go to Run > Edit configurations, choose your configuration below the Node.js option at left;

Screen shot for detail:
https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/1/AAC1WJBhh1RUnIBZEaG3YQ80iMswJH2XmFqb4GtiYwqj2A/12/11986044/png/1024x768/3/1413997200/0/2/Captura%20de%20tela%202014-10-22%2013.52.47.png/exYBAGzU3uZwj45i3XxZkgPKb_mfyL_O_q3EFRK5pFk

Comment: http://ask.make-money-article.com/que/19180702

Answer (score 1):

Possible since WebStorm 9 - see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/live-edit-updates-in-webstorm-9/